# Embedded video thumb has been displayed on all overlay windows

Tags: blocks, nodes

I have been created a block to display YouTube videos on my website ,When ever i tried to open admin windows that video thumbnail has been displaying on every overlay windows how can i disable that any suggestions ?

---

Screenshot :

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try [CSS z-index Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
>
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element
>   with a lower stack order.
>
> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

Try setting a `higher` value to the overlay or a `lower` value to the youtube player.